# How to create virtual users in vsftpd?

Tags: virtualization, ftp, users, chroot, vsftpd

I am running vsftpd on my Debian squeeze server. I configured it to chroot local users into their /home/ directory. Now, the problem is that users' web pages are outside of their /home/ directories (this is to allow for non world-readable home directories). But users should be able to upload files to their web pages. Now I think it would be best to use virtual users so they can use their normal username/password combination to access their home directories, and something like username.web to access their web pages.
Now, is there a way to configure vsftpd so I don't have to create a virtual user everytime I add a new 'real' user? And a way to allow the usage of users' normal passwords for their username.web login?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using bind mounts. This way you can keep the existing setup. Just make sure that the permissions are set up correctly.

As in:

```
mount --bind /web/pages/for/user1 /home/user1/webhome
```